# Fix for a mail account

Tags: email, imap, gmail

I've no time to install a mail server on my Ubuntu server and I have a client who needs to receive emails on his email account (the domain is registered with my hosting).

What's the best solution to forward the mails to a temporary gmail account (maybe just with apache)?

Comment: Forwarding mail with Apache? I think you're getting slightly confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think you need to change Apache to alter your mail routing

You need to set your MX records to those advised by your mail provider (Google in this case, but the looks of things). You set your MX records in DNS. So, you need to contact your DNS provider for this to be done

I would guess that your DNS provider is the same company that you bought your domains from. But, if you share the domain name, then it's possible to check who hosts your DNS

Comment: Ok i've updated the MX records. Now Google says I have to wait 48 hours. Just the first two are enough ? ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. Priority 10, ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.  20 .

Comment: Yep. You have a primary MX of aspmx.l.google.com and if that is unavailable the fallback is alt1.aspmx.l.google.com. If they are the only two records that Google have suggested, then I'd stick with that. Wait for DNS to refresh where required, and you should be good to go. If you're happy with this, then please could you accept an answer to your question?

Comment: I've accepted the answer, google lists 10 MX records. My hosting service has 2 records by default, so I just set that ones so far... is it working anyway ?

Comment: 2 records will be fine. As for if it's working, I have no idea - I can't test an address I don't know :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've control over the domain settings, why not setting up Google Apps?

Comment: Ok i've registered and updated the MX records. Now Google says I have to wait 48 hours. Just to be sure: Are the first two MX parameters are enough, or should I add all of them ? ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. Priority 10, ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.  20 .

Answer (score 0):

Details on Google Apps can be [found here](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html), with the [FAQ](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/faq.html) and [setup instructions](http://www.google.com/support/a/?hl=en) are provided.  It'll get you up and running within minutes (plus however long your TTL on your MX records is).

Comment: Ok i've registered and updated the MX records. Now Google says I have to wait 48 hours. Just to be sure: Are the first two MX parameters are enough, or should I add all of them ? ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. Priority 10, ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.  20 .